# Angular: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken NgxMqttServiceConfig

Tags: angular, typescript, mqtt, ngxs

I am new to Angular and facing an issue with no solution.

Basically I build an simple MQTT application using the latest version of Angular and the ngx-mqtt "library". But when starting the application I get the following error:

> R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_MqttService -> _MqttService -> InjectionToken NgxMqttServiceConfig -> InjectionToken NgxMqttServiceConfig]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken NgxMqttServiceConfig!

Do you know what I am doing wrong here?

Additional Information:

main.ts

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import routeConfig from './route';
import { MqttModule } from 'ngx-mqtt';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routeConfig) ,
    MqttModule
    
  ]  
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppComponent,
        BrowserModule,
        MqttModule.forRoot(MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS)
      ],
      providers: [
        MqttModule
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import {
  IMqttMessage,
  IMqttServiceOptions,
  MqttService,
  IPublishOptions,
  MqttModule,
  MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS,
  MqttClientService
} from 'ngx-mqtt';
import { IClientSubscribeOptions } from 'mqtt-browser';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, MaterialModule, MqttModule],
  providers:[MqttModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'MQTT_Example';

  constructor(private _mqttService: MqttService) { //this leads to the error!

  }
}
```

I also tried:

MqttModule.forRoot(MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS)

But It did'nt helped.

How to reproduce?

1. Create the angular application --> ng new mqtt_example
2. Install ngx-mqtt --> npm install ngx-mqtt --save
3. Write the following in the file app.component.ts

constructor(private _mqttService: MqttService) {
}

4. Run the application --> ng serve --open

Answer (score 3):

You should register all related to `MqttModule` providers while bootstrapping application:

**main.ts**

```
import { importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
...

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routeConfig) ,
    importProvidersFrom(MqttModule.forRoot(MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS)),
    ...
```

Comment: Yap, I agree, call `MqttModule.forRoot(...)`

Comment: Updated the main.ts file as per your suggestion but unfortunately I am receiving the same error.

Comment: @yurzui please find the project under the following link:

[Link] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-v1nycc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @SohaibIjaz If you're using ssr then you need to update it in two places. You forgot to add inside `app.config.ts`

Comment: @yurzui Thank you very much! I atleast got rid of the error. But now I am receiving the error "Websocket ist not defined". Eventhough I tried `(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');` in the app.component.ts file

Comment: Create a separated ts file with this code and import it before everything

Comment: @SohaibIjaz If you need additional help then please create a small github repository with reproduction of your issue so I can take a look and help

Comment: @yurzui I have created the git repo under the following link https://github.com/sohaib-96/angular-mqtt

Comment: @SohaibIjaz What should I run to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @yurzui just download the code and run the following command in the NodeJS command prompt "ng serve --open". And then you should see the error in the console.

Comment: @SohaibIjaz I see `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1884/' failed: `. You should add `import './ws.polly-fill';` only inside `main.server.ts` as the first import.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using `importProvidersFrom` to the bootstrap providers, also there is no need to add the separate providers array for app component.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MqttModule, MqttService } from 'ngx-mqtt';
import 'zone.js';

const routeConfig: any = [];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, MqttModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private _mqttService: MqttService) {}
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter(routeConfig), importProvidersFrom(MqttModule)],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I also tried in this way but receive the following error:

NG0400: A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first.

Comment: @SohaibIjaz please modify the stackblitz and share back with the issue replicated also update the Same on the question

Comment: please find the project under this link:
`
[link]**(https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-v1nycc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** `